# iOS how to understand symbolicated errors

Tags: ios, swift, crash, symbolicatecrash, dsym

I'm using swift to code. I have symbolicated errors but I still can't understand exactly what the error means. I can see these informations

- The class name
- The function name

Does it contain any other information like

- Line number
- Type of error (like array out of index..)

or more?

```
objc_retain @ 0xa
-[PFDecoder decodeDictionary:] @ 0x3d, PFDecoder.m : 86
-[PFDecoder decodeObject:] @ 0x13, PFDecoder.m : 112
#ERROR!
#ERROR!
#ERROR!
_TFV4Cozy11CozyConfigs14checkAnalyticsfMS0_FT_T_ @ 0xa2
_TFC4Cozy11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb @ 0x18a
_TToFC4Cozy11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb @ 0x10a
-[NSObject(TLDelegateSW) tlsw_application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] @ 0x45
-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] @ 0x117
-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] @ 0x933
-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] @ 0x557
__84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke @ 0x23
-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] @ 0x81
__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke @ 0xb
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ @ 0xb
__CFRunLoopDoBlocks @ 0xd7
__CFRunLoopRun @ 0x2f5
CFRunLoopRunSpecific @ 0x1db
CFRunLoopRunInMode @ 0x69
-[UIApplication _run] @ 0x22d
UIApplicationMain @ 0x59f
main @ 0x86
start @ 0x1
```

This is another crash log which is shorter.(maybe it'll be easier to explain)

```
_TFFV4Cozy10CardLoader10initializeFMS0_FT4viewGSqCSo6UIView_14tutorialActiveSb_T_U0_FTGSQPSs9AnyObject__GSQCSo7NSError__T_ @ 0x2720
_TFFV4Cozy10CardLoader10initializeFMS0_FT4viewGSqCSo6UIView_14tutorialActiveSb_T_U0_FTGSQPSs9AnyObject__GSQCSo7NSError__T_ @ 0xe44
__72-[BFTask(Private) continueWithMainThreadResultBlock:executeIfCancelled:]_block_invoke @ 0x50, BFTask+Private.m : 52
__41-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withBlock:]_block_invoke_2 @ 0x8, BFTask.m : 287
@ 0x13a8
@ 0x1368
@ 0x597c
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ @ 0x8
__CFRunLoopRun @ 0x5d0
CFRunLoopRunSpecific @ 0x188
@ 0xb5a0
UIApplicationMain @ 0x5cc
main @ 0x70
@ 0x2a04
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one seems like it crashes in the checkAnalytics method of your CozyConfigs class

Comment: _TFC4Cozy11AppDelegate11applicationfS0_FTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVSs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPSs9AnyObject____Sb @ 0x18a


what does this mean?

Comment: and how much information can I get from this log? Only function name or can I get crash line and what is the crash error (like index out of range)?

Comment: Are you doing anything with dictionaries in that method?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can get the error message but that number at the end of the line might be the line that it occurs. Anything relevant on the 18th line?

Comment: only boolean values, array, and contains(array, somevalue) check

Comment: 18th line doesn't exist (function is 15 line long). Also the global variables I use in the function aren't defined in the 18th line.

Comment: btw its not 18 its 24 since its hexadecimal. I use a variable with a if case there.     static let SkipOurAnalytics = false and used as             if SkipOurAnalytics { ... }. I don't think it has something to do with line number since the second bug is like 1231231th line